# Cursor to get all distinct values from each table and field on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I'm trying to do a cursor over a SQL Server database to get all the Distinct values from each table.
I want the table with values to look like this:

```
 Database   Schema   Table   Field   Value
     A         dbo     T1     F1       1
     A         dbo     T1     F1       2
     A         dbo     T1     F1       3
    ...        ...     ...    ...     ...
```

My trouble is that when I try to put the database name, with QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG), It doesn't evaluate the function, and instead, it writes the function to the table that I want to generate.
I've tried with single/double quotes without results.

¿How should I write the query? Thanks!

```
Set Nocount ON

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'SELECT DISTINCT ' + ''' QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '''+' As DBName,'+ + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS Datos' + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%' 

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd);
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

Set Nocount OFF
```

BTW: I took the code and edited it from an example ([Get distinct values from each table and each column with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088242/get-distinct-values-from-each-table-and-each-column-with-sql-server))

Comment: You should not use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to get the schema of an object. MS admits they are not reliable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql

Comment: Re INFORMATION_SCHEMA and determining schemas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310746/121544

Comment: Thanks about that.. Had no idea that was not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not get quotes quite right with the `''' QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '''`. It should be `''' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '''`.

Quotes are escaped by doubling them up e.g.

```
SELECT 'blah' --> blah
SELECT 'it''s' --> it's
SELECT ' Alex''' + 's pen' -->  Alex's pen
```

Syntax error

```
SELECT 'it's' --> syntax error
```

The finished query is here:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'SELECT DISTINCT ''' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + ''' As DBName, ''' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''' AS [Schema], ''' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ''' AS ColumnName, '
    +  QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS Datos ' +
    'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%' 

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd);
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Notes:

- Remove `QUOTENAME` if you do not want the string to be surrounded by `[]` (square brakets)
- A comment on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`: for your purposes this view WILL return correct data as stated in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310746/6305294 (comment from @ShannonSeverance). What this view lacks is detailed information about column properties.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected! And thanks for the aclaration about Information_Shema